# Determine the expected value and the probability of some events (applicative probability problem)

Tags: probability

Suppose that the time that a phone call lasts is a random variable with density function given by:

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t} & \text{if } t > 0 \\
    0 & \text{another case}
\end{cases}
$$
I want to first determine some probabilities for the call:

**1.** Takes longer than 5 minutes.
We have, by the apparent continuity of the random variable

$$P(X >5)= \int_{5}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}=[-e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}]_{5}^{\infty}=e^{-1}$$

**2.** Takes between 5 and 6 minutes.

$$P(5 \leq X \leq 6)= \int_{5}^{6} \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}=[-e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}]_{5}^{6}=e^{-1}-e^{-\frac{6}{5}}$$

**3.** Takes less than 5 minutes.

$$P(X< 5)= \int_{0}^{5} \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}=[-e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}]_{0}^{5}=1-e^{-1}$$

**4.** Takes less than 6 minutes given that it took at least 3 minutes

Here note that if $A=\{X<6 \}$ and $B=\{X\geq 3 \}$, then $A \cap B = \{3 \leq X <6 \}$, as $P(B) = \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}=e^{-\frac{3}{5}}$ and $P(A \cap B)=\int_{3}^{6} \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}=-e^{-\frac{6}{5}}+e^{-\frac{3}{5}} $

Then

$$P\{X<6|X \geq 3 \}=\frac{-e^{-\frac{6}{5}}+e^{-\frac{3}{5}}}{e^{-\frac{3}{5}}}=1-e^{-\frac{3}{5}}$$

But now, if $C(t)$ be the amount that must be paid by the user for every call that lasts $t$ minutes

$$C(t)=\begin{cases}
    500 & \text{if } 0 <t \leq 5 \\
    750 & \text{if } 5 <t \leq 10 \\
    100t & \text{if } t \geq 10
\end{cases}$$

And I want to find **the mean cost of a call**, then I can consider

\begin{align*}
E(C(t)) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |C(t)|f(t) & = & \int_{0}^{5} 500 \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t} & + & \int_{5}^{10} 750 \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t} & + & \int_{10}^{\infty} 100t \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{1}{5}t} \\
& & = & 100(5-5e^{-1}) & + & e^{-2}(750e-750) & + & 1500e^{-2}
\end{align*}

What I have indicated is correct? was there any correction? any help is welcome!!

Comment: There's at least one typographical error in (3).

Comment: @whuber You're right, thank you, it was  less than 5 minutes.